# Can't figure out mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

I'm new to PHP and MySQL -> I'm not good yet.
Today I came across the problem. I have a query that joins 2 tables 'votes' and 'stories'
Here it is:

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name WHERE stories.st_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 32 DAY) 
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes ASC LIMIT 10
```

I need to modify it so it only selects information from 'stories' table where field **showing = 1**

A simple query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM stories WHERE showing = 1
```

But I have no idea how to implement it the first query where I join two databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories, votes 
WHERE stories.id = votes.item_name AND stories.showing = 1 AND stories.st_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 32 DAY)
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes ASC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name $date 
WHERE showing=1
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes ASC LIMIT 10
```

Simply stick the `where` in there. Make sure to place it in the right order though.

Comment: Just in case I forgot to mention it in my question, the $date variable is this "WHERE stories.st_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 32 DAY)" so after it I would stick in AND stories.showing = 1, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Its no problem just to add it in, since it is the base table of the joins:

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name $date 
WHERE stories.showing = 1
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Just in case I forgot to mention it in my question, the $date variable is this "WHERE stories.st_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 32 DAY)" so after it I would stick in AND stories.showing = 1, correct?

Answer (score 1):

change your query to

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories 
JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name 
WHERE stories.showing = 1 
GROUP BY stories.id 
ORDER BY total_votes ASC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the HAVING showing = 1 and it should fix your issue.